# progress on Suffrage and Vox Populi down to zero?

Tags: bug, vote-to-close, badges

I have been working on the Close Votes review queue for a while and I'm fairly certain I saw some progress towards the Suffrage and Vox Populi badges a few weeks ago.

But in the past few days the progress it's been down to 0/30 and 0/40 respectively. To verify yesterday I ran out of flags again. Still at zero.

Did I do something wrong or the closing votes no longer count towards these badges? Or it's a bug?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both [Suffrage](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/804/suffrage) and [Vox Populi](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1108/vox-populi) concern *question* and *answer* votes, not flags or close votes.  To qualify for those, you'd have to vote on 10 questions in addition to 30 questions or answers.

You can check out [this Meta Stack Exchange answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188732/175248) for a full listing of the requirements for both of those badges.

Comment: ACK. I guess it was a bug that I had progress before, fixed now :) Thx.

Comment: @DanCornilescu:  I doubt there was any bug.  You may have voted on a question or and answer prior to casting flags, and believed that it was the flags rather than the votes that counted.

Comment: It seems I misunderstood the meaning of the progress indication for those badges, I didn't realize it represents a day's progress only, reset daily. All good. Thx.

Comment: @Makoto: I think that you didn't explain the number of votes that you have per day correctly: _Ten can be used only on questions ("Q-votes") and 30 can be used on **either questions or answers** ("QA-votes")._ (Emphasis mine.) So, it's sufficient to only vote on questions.