# Why can't I get the "Vox Populi" Badge?

Tags: support

I've used the maximum votes in a day plenty of times (more than 10) and I still can't get the badge. It looks like my daily limit is less than 40 every time.

Comment: Did you vote on questions and answers?

Comment: Is this related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314882/progress-on-suffrage-and-vox-populi-down-to-zero

Answer (score 53, accepted):

According to [List of all badges with full descriptions - Moderation Badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188732/195099),

> You get two types of votes per day: ten can be used only on questions
>   ("Q-votes") and 30 can be used on either questions or answers
>   ("QA-votes"). When you vote on a question, the system tries to use
>   your Q-votes before your QA-votes.
>
> When you only have five QA-votes left for the day, the "You have n
>   votes left today" counter starts to appear after you cast votes.
>
> Once the counter starts, it never goes back up on that day. Therefore,
>   if you start a day by voting mostly on answers, the counter can start
>   when you have more than five total votes (i.e. including both Q and
>   QA) left, **making it impossible for you to reach 40 votes that day**.

Comment: so I have to use first my 10 Q-votes and then the rest?

Comment: Yep.  That'll get you 40 votes, which will get you your badge.

Comment: I'd say the description of the badge is hence somewhat misleading and should be more clear to prevent some disappointment of users.. Moreover, I've got 39/40 and can't upvote questions, but added a couple of upvotes to comments and it's still 39/40, so I'm not sure if I understand your explanation.

Comment: @YakovL - Upvoting on comments gets you nothing.  Literally.  I don't think there's a single badge you can earn from upvoting comments.  Only questions and answers.  Upvote 10 questions out of the gate, and then upvote 30 more questions **or** answers and you should earn your Vox Populi.

Comment: @JohnnyBones yes, I got that from the description you provided (some time after I've commented, though). What I'm saying is the description of the badge is not quite clear and if the words "maximum 40 votes" were a link to the whole description, with all these rules, it would be more helpful.

Comment: @JohnnyBones So can I upvote 40 questions and get the badge?

Comment: @Elixir0101 - Yes, it's that easy.